# Abstract class 'instantiation' with a body of its methods

Tags: java

I am starting java programming and I came across abstract classes. I know that you cannot instantiate them without creating concrete classes which extend them to become the subclass. However, I got really confused when I tried this code and it runs ok.

```
abstract class Communication{
   public void FirstMethod()
   {
       System.out.println("I am first method()\n");
   }
}

public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Communication communication = new Communication() {
         @Override
         public void FirstMethod(){
             super.FirstMethod();
         }
      };

      communication.FisrtMethod();
   }
}
```

Output is: I am first method().
If I modify it to:

```
Communication communication = new Communication() {
         @Override
         public void FirstMethod(){
             System.out.println("I've been called from Main");
         }
      };
```

The output is: I've been called from Main.
Could somebody please explain if this is a kind of instantiation or what concept is this?

Comment: This is so-called anonymous inner class.

Comment: as ntalbs said, this is `anonymous inner classes` it's somehow a technique ?! you can use it when you want to create instance of a class, and override some of it' method without actually creating a new subclass that extends the first. mostly used in Listeners...

Comment: As a side note, I guess they should be less used now that there are [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is termed as

> Anonymous Class

Definition:
An inner class declared without a class name is known as an **anonymous inner** class.

In case of anonymous inner classes, we declare and instantiate them at the same time. Generally, they are used whenever you need to override the method of a class or an interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **anonymous inner class**. This way you can implement an interface or abstract class without having to find a name for it and instantiate it at the same time. This concept is useful when you use a certain implementation just once.

The construct looks always like that:

```
new SomeClass() {
    //implementation of methods
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as anonymous class. The anonymous class definition allows you to provide a class definition within code and it has no formal name. The anonymous class expression has the class definition and instance creation expression.This is not limited to abstract classes but also for interfaces and concrete classes. 
        For example

```
abstract class A { }
// so the anonymous class expression is 

A a = new A() {// class definition };

// This will actually create an instance of a
// class that extends the abstract class A 
// that java will create at run time
```

You can even use anonymous class expression in the method arguments.Example of this is a Comparator in Collections.sort() method;

```
  Collections.sort(listOfValues,new Comparator<Value>(){
      public int compare(Value v1, Value v2){
        // method implemetation.
      }
  })
```